# PHP: prevent duplicated tags in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySql Table For Tags Like This:

```
| id |   name    |
| 1  |   Linux   |
| 2  |  Windows  |
| 3  |   Unix    |
| 4  |    Dos    |
| 5  |  FreeBSD  |
```

In News Page User add New Tags Like This:

```
Linux,OpenBSD,Test
```

Now, `Linux` Previously added, So I need To add `ONLY` OpenBSD and Test Into Tags Table. My Mean Is: how to `INSERT` tags if User tags is New?!

Comment: You can make that column 'unique' so that it will not accept duplicate information. Only one problem - `linux != Linux`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Put a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `name` column.
2. Use `INSERT IGNORE` so that inserting a column where `name` already exists simply skips that row. eg:

   ```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO tags (name) VALUES ('Linux'), ('OpenBSD'), ('Test');
   ```
3. Because you have different casings in your data [eg: `linux` vs `Linux`] you either need to make sure that you are using a case-insensitive coallation in your database like `utf8_latin1_ci` [`ci` stands for case-insensitive] or be sure to use `strtolower()` on your data prior to inserting it.

Comment: You have a typo `INGORE` Unless you meant "Al Gore" but I doubt that ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was paying tribute to the man that invented the Internet. :P

Comment: *Ah*, that's what it was ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Like Jay suggested, normalise the data, then make the column `UNIQUE`, and use something like `INSERT IGNORE INTO yourTags(name) VALUES(?),(?),(?)` (and send in the three values as parameters). I'm also assuming that the ID column is `AUTO INCREMENT`.